# Can I remove a HTML element using Cypress?

Tags: html, dom, cypress, element

Is it possible to use Cypress to find and delete an element from the HTML? And how to do it?

**Edit:** This works:

```
cy.get(selector).then((elem) => {
  const elemHtml = elem.get(0)
  elemHtml.remove()
})
```

Comment: Please add the code that you tried.

Comment: You can, but I imagine it would take some effort in writing the code.
`cy.document().invoke( 'write', html)`

Comment: This code above worked, but I don't know if is this the right way or not

Comment: Yep that's correct. Any errors with this code?

Comment: No errors... Just work

Answer (score 5):

Variation on @krema's answer:

```js
cy.get(selector).invoke('remove');
```

Answer (score 2):

*get()* yields the DOM element(s) it found which can then be removed.

```
cy.get(selector).then($el => $el.remove());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use embedded jquery in cypress:

```
Cypress.$(yourElementSelector).remove();
```

Comment: And the syntax is wrong anyway.

Comment: Edit done. LOL Cypress is built on top of jQuery, did you know?

Comment: Still seems wrong

Comment: This is certainly a viable solution. It just lacks the retries you would get from `cy.get()`